# how can we open the android contact activity programatically?

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can i open the android inbuilt View Contact Activity
Programatically.

I am having a list of contacts in my activity and i want to show the contact details on the selection of list Item, so i basically want to know to which android activity i should send the intent in order to open that activity.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reach Contacts in Android, you probably want to read on in the [Contacts class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html).

Answer (score 6):

Use the `ACTION_VIEW` action in your intent, with the `content://contacts/people/1` URI (see javadoc of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more details)